# Using 'Deploy to Bluemix' button fails to deploy

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

Using the deploy from another repository, e.g.
https://hub.jazz.net/deploy/index.html?repository=https%3A%2F%2Fhub.jazz.net%2Fgit%2Fremkohdev1%2Fremkohdev-mean1%2F

Trying deploy the application described here
http://www.remkohde.com/2015/08/29/how-to-create-a-mean-stack-app/

from this JazzHub repository
https://hub.jazz.net/project/remkohdev1/remkohdev-mean1

I am using the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button, and it all works, until it tries to deploy to Bluemix in the last step.

The deployment log says
"FAILED
Could not find service MongoLab-j6 to bind to app-remkohdev1-1539"

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button to create the service for you, you need to add another block to your manifest.yml like this:

```
declared-services:
  MongoLab-j6:
    label: mongolab
    plan: sandbox
```

The above code will create a MongoLab service with a the name MongoLab-j6. Then, it will bind it to your application.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html#deploy_button

Note that the 'cf' command line tool will ignore this section. It only works for the Deploy to Bluemix button

Answer (score 0):

When you click the 'deploy to bluemix' button, the deploy phase in the 'Deploy to Bluemix' will fail binding the service to the application, because the MongoDb service must match the exact service name as in the manifest.yml file, and the service does not exist in your space.

You must create the MongoDb service with the matching name 'MongoLab-j6' as described in the manifest.yml file of the app, before you press the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button, or you can add a line to your new application's manifest and edit the name to your own MongoDb service name and then redeploy.
- services
- yourmongodb-s1